# Folder Copy in win32 application in VS 2010

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am working on the following code

```
 void copyDir(void)
 {
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT s = { 0 };
    s.hwnd = hwnd;
    s.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    s.pTo = "E:\\dest\0";
    s.pFrom = "Dir\\*\0";
    s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT;
    SHFileOperation( &s );

 }
```

the above function successfully copy a folder and subfolders to destination path, the only problem i am getting is the windows prompt when folder doesnt exist at destination path, the windows prompt for "Do you want to create this folder", how can i bypass this prompt and the windows progress-bar which is shown by windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this flag: FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR

```
s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR;
```

Copy and Move operations can specify destination directories that do not exist. In those cases, the system attempts to create them and normally displays a dialog box to ask the user if they want to create the new directory. **To suppress this dialog box and have the directories created silently, set the FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR flag in fFlags**.

[`SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)